# mysql copy value from temp_table to table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

1 have 2 table, temp_table and table, both are `MyISAM`.

temp_table (Write frequently, run cron job every minute insert data)

```
id（auto_increment），title（varchar(200)），content（varchar(500)），date(DATETIME), mykey(tinyint(1) Default 1)
```

table (Read frequently, for custom search, update from temp_table with cron job every 10 minutes)

```
id（int(11)），title（varchar(200)），content（varchar(500)），date(DATETIME), hour(smallint(2))
```

Now, the data are **~300MB/table** and every update will transfer **2,000-3,000 rows**.

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../connection.php';
mysql_select_db("news",$connextion);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (hour,id,title,content,date) values '".date('H')."',SELECT id, title,content,date from temp_table where mykey = '1'");
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE temp_table SET mykey='2' WHERE mykey = '1'");
//if data has transfer, update mykey='2' for a mark.
mysql_close($connextion);
```

But nothing `INSERT INTO table`, how to write a correct mysql query and is this way more efficient? I need less mysql connection time and lower memory usage. thanks.

PS: temp_table has some rule for checking if title is duplicate, so temp_table can not delete, and table will be cleared every day if date is 1 month ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (hour,id,title,content,date) values ('".date('H')."',SELECT id, title,content,date from temp_table where mykey = '1'")) or die('error while inserting');`